# Error with MapModel in primefaces jsf

Tags: java, google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I'm a beginner in jsf. I want to use gmap , when i create a new variable

```
    private MapModel emptyModel;
```

i see this error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/primefaces/model/map/MapModel;
```

How can i solve it ?

Comment: Did you include primefaces.jar and what version of Primefaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with an easy way

check it http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/gmapBasic.jsf

```
<p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBRID"   
        style="width:600px;height:400px" />
```

Comment: I used
`<p:gmap id="gmap" center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="ROADMAP"   
    style="width:600px;height:400px"  
    model="#{addBean.emptyModel}"   
    onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);"   
    widgetVar="map" />`
but emptyModel is error and i can't solve it